# Changes in org-agenda-custom-commands?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I had set up an Agenda view for showing today's tasks and TODOs with tags "UPCOMING" or "PROJECT":

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
       '(("w" "Agenda + TODOs"
          ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1)))
           (tags-todo "UPCOMING")
           (tags-todo "PROJECT")))))
```

Now, after updating org-mode yesterday, it still works fine, but instead of showing just today's tasks, it shows the entire week.

Any idea what might have caused this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which version you upgraded to, you might find that `org-agenda-ndays` does not exist any longer. Try this:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(("w" "Agenda + TODOs"
      ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span (quote day))))
       (tags-todo "UPCOMING")
       (tags-todo "PROJECT")))))
```

instead.